# Can the SIMD directive in OpenMP really speed up execution?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, vmware, simd, multicore

I wrote two programs prog1.c and prog2.c in a VMware virtual machine including 2 cpu cores. Prog1.c has the openmp directive  # pragma OMP SIMD, and prog2.c does not have it.

prog1.c

```
 void bgra2rgb(const char *src,char*dst,int w,int h)
    {
    #pragma omp simd
        for(int y=0;y<h;++y)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<w;++x)
            {
                dst[(y*w+x)*3  ] = src[(y*w+x)*4 + 2];
                dst[(y*w+x)*3+1] = src[(y*w+x)*4 + 1];
                dst[(y*w+x)*3+2] = src[(y*w+x)*4 + 0];
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    int main()
    {
        char bgra_mat[480*640*4];
        char rgb_mat[480*640*3];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i++)
            bgra2rgb(bgra_mat,rgb_mat,480,640);
    
    }
```

prog2.c

```
void bgra2rgb(const char *src,char*dst,int w,int h)
{

    for(int y=0;y<h;++y)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<w;++x)
        {
            dst[(y*w+x)*3  ] = src[(y*w+x)*4 + 2];
            dst[(y*w+x)*3+1] = src[(y*w+x)*4 + 1];
            dst[(y*w+x)*3+2] = src[(y*w+x)*4 + 0];
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    char bgra_mat[480*640*4];
    char rgb_mat[480*640*3];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i++)
        bgra2rgb(bgra_mat,rgb_mat,480,640);
}
```

The prog1.c is compiled by "gcc  -fopt-info -mavx -fopenmp  -o prog1 prog1.c" . The prog2.c is compiled by "gcc   -fopenmp  -o prog2 prog2.c"
But the execution time of prog1 and prog2 are same, why ? What's wrong with me ?

Comment: You forgot to enable any optimization, the default is `-O0` (debug mode), so of course GCC decides to ignore the hint that it could vectorize!!  `gcc -O2 -march=native` is your best bet for seeing a speedup; `-O3` enables auto-vectorization even without OpenMP.  (Although IDK whether the normal or OpenMP vectorizer will recognize that byte shuffle: you might need to manually vectorize with intrinsics, especially since the repeating pattern length (3) isn't a multiple of 2)

Comment: See [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) about default optimization levels.

Comment: almost a duplicate of [Efficiency of OpenMP vs optimisation levels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64722158), but that's about parallelization, not SIMD.  And finally found an actual duplicate, by searching on `openmp simd "-O0"` on google.  [pragma omp for simd does not generate vector instructions in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61154047)